# Iterate ALL the elements of a circular 2D array exactly once given a random starting element

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, iteration

We are given a 2-dimensional array `A[n,m]` with `n` rows and `m` columns and an element of that array chosen at random `R`.
Think of the array as being circular in that when we visit `A[n-1, m-1]` the next element we visit would be `A[0, 0]`.

Starting with element `R`, we want to visit each element exactly once and call function `foo()` before moving to the next element.

The following is my first implementation but there is a bug. The bug being that if we start at row `x` somewhere between `0` and `n-1`, we will not visit element from `0` to `x-1` in that column.

```
// Init - pretend rand() always returns valid index in range
curr_row = rand();
curr_col = rand();

// Look at each column once
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) 
{
  for (; curr_row < n; ++curr_row) 
  {
    foo(A[curr_row][curr_col]);
  }
  curr_row = 0;
  curr_col = (curr_col + 1) % m;
}
```

What is a clean way to do this traversal such that we meet the above requirements?

Comment: What is the declaration of `A`? And, what do you think `A[curr_row, curr_col]` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move to the next index, and check whether you are back at the start, in which case, stop:

```
// should be something that guarantees in-range indices
curr_row = rand();
curr_col = rand();
int i = curr_row, j = curr_col;
do {
    foo(A[i][j]);
    ++j;
    if (j == n) {
        j = 0;
        ++i;
        if (i == m) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}while(i != curr_row || j != curr_col);
```

This doesn't do what your implementation does, but what the question title asks for.

Answer (score 1):

quite rusty with c , but it should be the same:

```
// Init - pretend rand() always returns valid index in range
curr_row = rand();
curr_col = rand();

//first row
for(int j=curr_col;j<m;++j)
  foo(A[curr_row][j]);

//rest of the rows
for(int i=(curr_row+1)%n;i!=curr_row;i=(i+1)%n)
  for(int j=0;j<m;++j)
      foo(A[i][j]);

//first row , going over missed cells
for(int j=0;j<curr_col;++j)
  foo(A[curr_row][j]);
```

if you care a lot about performance , you can also divide the second loop so that there won't be a "%" at all .

another alternative , since C has 2d arrays in a simple array:

```
// Init - pretend rand() always returns valid index in range
curr_row = rand();
curr_col = rand();

int start=curr_row*m+curr_col;
int maxCell=n*m;
int end=(start-1)%maxCell;    

for(int i=start;i!=end;i=(i+1)%maxCell)
  foo(A[i]);
foo(A[end]);
```

could have a tiny math bug here and there ,but the idea is ok.

Answer (score -1):

`A[curr_row, curr_col]` is *not* the syntax used to access a member of a multidimensional array; instead, you want `A[curr_row][curr_col]`, assuming the array was declared correctly. `A[curr_row, curr_col]` will invoke the comma operator, which effectively computes the first value, then throws it away and calculates the second value, then indexes the array with that value.

Comment: Kind of off topic ...but sorry got a little sloppy I guess

Comment: Not off-topic at all.  It is *essential* for this question that you know how to declare and index 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: the important thing here is the algorithm , not the syntax . same question could be for any other language.